Changing Billing Details for CiviCRM Spark Instance
I´m currently paying for a CiviCRM Spark Instance via credit card. Now I want to change the credit card details but cannot find any information about it in the menu.
Where can I change the billing details for my CiviCRM Instance?

There is currently no self-serve option for updating Spark billing details. You will need to email spark(at)civicrm(dot)org and request a Stripe Billing link to update your payment method.

thanks for the info
